I am looking for an Italian film about women's fortunes in society
This particular film is of recent date (probably late 90s, early 00s).
The movie is constructed as a polyptych. The stories revolved around fortunes of women in different time periods of the modern Italian history.
All episodes, stories are told from a point of view of different women. I do remember three stories. The focus is on women's condition in society and economy. 
One involved young female student caught in dilemma whether to move to Rome and further her studies or to marry and lead a morose bourgeoise life (1960s).
The second story was set in declining industrial period (1970s, 80s). Issues involved were unemployment, rising female service economy and male frustrations.
The third and, within film narrative, the last story was set in rural environment (time period, sometime between 1900 and 1930s). Young farming couple was desperately trying to improve their living conditions. They were saving for something, probably for better piece of land. But their effort was in vain due to unexpected new child.
The tone of this film is heavy, gray, sisyphean...

Could it be a  documentary film?
Vogliamo anche le rose (2007) https://www.dokfest-muenchen.de/events/view/500?lang=en

checked it, but this is not it. it was definitely a narrative / non documentary film. i have difficulties in adding some additional information regarding this film.  information collected above is all, best i can do.
